# useFetch() custom hook not fetching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

Does anyone have an idea on why this `useFetch` hook is not fetching anything? Chrome Devtools says the beerId is fine, it is passed in, it is read by the inner async function, but the fetch is not sent at all. Network tab shows no API call. Therefore, the output is an empty object, not good. What am I missing? The API is otherwise fine, my other calls return responses alright. Cheers.

```
export const useFetch = (beerId, initialValue) => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialValue); 
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchBeerById() {
            try {
                setLoading(true)
                const res = await fetch(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${beerId}`);
                const beer = await res.json();
                setData(beer)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } finally {
                setLoading(false)
            }
        }
        fetchBeerById()
    },[beerId])
    return { data, isLoading}
}
```

This is how I use it in the app:

```
const BeerDetails = () => {
  // get id from URL
  const params = useParams();
  const { beerId } = params;
  debugger
  // fetch that beer, apply local price
  const { data } = useFetch(beerId, {})
  const beer = usePriceBeer(data)
  
  // get the selected data from beer
  const selectBeerData = getSelectedBeerDetails(beer)
  const { name, image_url, abv, ibu, price, tagline, description } = 
  selectBeerData;
 
  return (...render jsx using above vars)
  
}
```

And here is what I see in the DevTools. For some reason, the `fetch` command is a dud. If I hover over `res` nothing pops up, the API call is not even fired. In fact, the whole `useEffect` block is just skipped, not even isLoading is set back to false.

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of how do you use this function?

Comment: ^^^ yes need to see how you are using it within your application

Comment: The code you posted works fine. As others have mentioned above, you should edit your question and add the way you use this custom hook.

Comment: thanks Guys, I have edited the question for more context. The useEffect hook is to blame but I don't know how to get this bloody thing to fire off...

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be data is null on the initial load and you get an empty object.

I tried to create a prototype for it and just return null if there is no data. So only return data when it exits with isLoading.

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-banzai-b2y0c

make sure to check lines 26 and 40

Comment: Hi Sodhi, this worked in the Sandbox - but it did not in the app. It's a mystery.

Comment: let’s check it together if you want.

Comment: Hello Sodhi, that would be great. When would it be convenient to you? We could hook up on Skype and share screen... cheers

Comment: Free free to contact me with me any item, we can arrange a call.

Answer (score 0):

How are you using your custom hook? If you are using it this way then it should be working as expected:

```
const App = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useFetch(10, {});

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return <p>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</p>;
};

export default App;
```

By the way the response returning from your API is an array not an object, You can change it to return a single object if you want:

```
const [beer] = await res.json();
setData(beer);
```

Comment: hi Sirwan, I have edited the question with more context. cheers